# Is there as many media staff as protestors in Ferguson?

Tags: united-states

In [Media making up the mob: Journalists amid protesters in Ferguson, Mo.](http://www.washingtonpost.com/news/morning-mix/wp/2014/08/20/media-making-up-the-mob-journalists-amid-protesters-in-ferguson-mo/) in the Washington Post, it's claimed there's as many media staff as protestors in Ferguson:

> Early Wednesday, Lowery estimated that the size of the group
>   protesting and the media covering it was about even — between 100 and
>   150 of each.

This claim is repeated in the summary text for a [tweet linking to the article](https://twitter.com/abbydphillip/status/502052531259052032).

Is it true?

Comment: That could easily be true *for that specific time period*. Reports (from the [NY Times](http://www.nytimes.com/2014/08/21/us/ferguson-missouri-protests.html?_r=0), for instance) say that a peaceful demonstration ended some time before midnight. In addition, the police made 47 arrests "late Tuesday". It stands to reason the remaining crowd "early Wednesday" was smaller than usual.

Comment: What is the basis for being skeptical of this claim?

Comment: @DVK do you mean *doubtful*? Because we should apply skepticism to every claim.

Comment: It wouldn't be the first time.  I've seen Dutch media reporting "massive public interest" in some royal event, where journalists outnumbered citizens 5-to-1.

Comment: @gerrit - surely you won't begrudge our masters from the 4th estate the right to be called "public" when they see feet to pretend to the title?

Comment: Related, and interesting: are the journalists *becoming* the news? http://ryanschuessler.com/2014/08/21/i-will-not-be-returning-to-ferguson/